# By-language challenges

Tags: discussion, tags

While looking through [rosetta-stone](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/rosetta-stone), I discovered that there are two types of questions tagged with it:

1. The type intended by the tag: answers with many different answers in different languages. Each answer shows off the answerer's programming language multilingualism.
2. [A single question](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/23423/9498) is tagged like this: different answers in different languages; no answer will be accepted. The challenge is looking for many different people to post solutions in different language and each language's shortest answer will get a mention. This was used like [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf), but as a challenge for each language.

#2 could be a good idea. Some challenges don't make since when each language is battling other languages and every language will have vastly different answers. It would be a challenge in any language. For example, I am drafting a challenge that requires each answer to [prove that its language is Turing Complete](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1489/9498). This would be more appropriate as a by-language challenge.

I'm proposing a new tag, something like [by-language](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/by-language). This tag would not be a challenge genre, but an addition to a genre. Any challenge with this tag would be doing a by-language challenge and apply the winning-criteria by language.

Problems:

- Is it a good idea to make challenges where no answer will be accepted?

Comment: accept? Why accept? It's just 1.5 upvotes + some extra visibility.

Comment: @JanDvorak I feel as if StackExchange was designed for answers to be accepted.

Comment: As I already commented on said question you proposed... I don't think there is really a difference. By-language challenges could also declare that user as the winner who has winning entries in the most languages, just as the original rosetta-stone challenges did. Whether these multilingual entries by a single user are presented within a single answer post - as in the rosetta-stone challenges - or multiple ones (one per language) - as in your by-language challenges - doesn't make a difference, imho. [tbc...]

Comment: [...] And you could still accept an answer: either the overall shortest answer; or the shortest answer submitted by the winning user (which would acknowledge the actual "winner" of the challenge).

Comment: That being said, I do agree that the rosetta-stone tag should be an add-on to one of the normal challenge types, as the type of scoring is completely independent of this multi-language feature.

Comment: @m.buettner I can't imagine rosetta-stone popularity-contest, though.

Comment: @JanDvorak yes, that may be the exception, but that is the only type of challenge (I can think of) where the winning criterion is not intrinsic to the answer itself - so I think PC have a somewhat exceptional role anyway.

Comment: Accepting an answer here is like declaring a winner. By definition, a [tag:By-Language] challenge can have many winners. Therefore, I would not accept an answer for a [tag:By-Language] challenge.

Comment: It's also worth mentioning that we don't need to meta post every time we create a new tag. Just *use* it, and maybe note that you intentionally created it for the challenge. Write the wiki for it. If it is popular, then it will stick. If nobody uses the tag for six months, then it will simply die. If it is obvious to the community that the tag is not useful, then they might edit your post to remove the tag. This happens often when new users post.